# How to Get data from react native-deck-swiper when swiped

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, swiper.js, react-native-swiper

I am using react native deck swipper to display arrays of data.

//ARRAYS OF DATA

```
    const docs = shuffleArray([
  {
    title: "Austin Wade",
    content: 22,
    featured_image: require("../../assets/images/beach.jpeg"),
    created_at: "2020-11-11T16:26:13.000000Z",
    news_url: "https://www.google.com",
    key: "caseex6qfO4TPMYyhorner",
  },..... more json arrays...])
```

**My problem is, i want to be able to extract the *news_url* when the card is swipped left, and also use the extracted URL to open expo inapp-browser that will display the webpage e.g [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**

I have written a function that opens a web browser.

**PLEASE CAN SOMEONE HELP ME**

//SWIPPER

```
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {/* <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 16 }}> */}
      <Swiper
        ref={useSwiper}
        cards={docs}
        cardIndex={0}
        backgroundColor="transparent"
        stackSize={2}
        showSecondCard
        cardHorizontalMargin={0}
        animateCardOpacity
        disableBottomSwipe
        renderCard={
            ((card) => <Cardz card={card} />)
        }
        onSwiped={(cardIndex) => {
          console.log(cardIndex);
        }}
        onSwipedAll={() => {
          console.log("onSwipedAll");
        }}
        onSwipedTop={() => {
          console.log(getLatestNews);
        }}
        onSwipedBottom={() => {
          // <Toast message={success} onDismiss={() => {}} />
        }}
        //swipping left, opens expo web browser
        onSwipedLeft={() => {
            _handleWebBrowserAsync(getNewsUrl);
            //Alert.alert();
        }}
      ></Swiper>
      {/* </View> */}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

//WEB BROSWER
//async function to open app inapp web browser

```
const _handleWebBrowserAsync = async (url) => {
    try {
        _addLinkingListener();
        await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url);
        //only calls this method in IOS Devices as it only
        //works for IOS Devices
        if (Constants.platform.ios) {
        _removeLinkingListener();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert("Error:", error.message);;
        console.log("Error:" + error.message);
    }
};
```

//CARD COMPONENT

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Image, ImageSourcePropType } from 'react-native'
import styles from './Card.styles'
const Cardz = ({ card }) => (
  <View activeOpacity={1} style={styles.card}>
    <Image
      style={styles.image}
      source={card.featured_image}
      resizeMode="cover"
    />
    <View style={styles.photoDescriptionContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{`${card.title}, ${card.content}`}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
export default Cardz
```

Answer (score 2):

There are [event callbacks](https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper#event-callbacks).

For example: There is `onSwiped` prop which is a

> function to be called when a card is swiped. it receives the swiped card index.

So, you'll get that index value which you'll use to get the object from the `docs` array. If the swiped index is `2`, you can get the object like this: `docs[2]`.

Comment: so probably getting the news url could be something like docs[2].news_url right?

Comment: Thanks @Sagar. The solution is console.log(docs[cardIndex]);

Comment: So i finally got the news_url using this =>  `docs[card].news_url`

Comment: i have one more problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606216/react-native-deck-swiper